# Non-uniform distribution random in golang

Tags: go, random, random-seed

Quoted from [league of legends](https://leagueoflegends.fandom.com/wiki/Critical_strike):

> The probability of a critical strike changes dynamically based on how many times the attack critically strikes. If an attack does not critically strike over multiple attempts, the probability will progressively increase for future attempts—this can occur vice versa, where multiple successful critical strikes will cause the probability to progressively decrease for future attempts.

If I understand correctly, the chance for an event to appear is progressively affected by previous times, i.e. `non-uniform distribution` randomization, right? Is there such a randomization algorithm in `golang`'s `math/rand`? If not, how can we implement it?

Comment: That's not just a non-uniform distribution. A PRNG isn't necessarily a uniform distribution, because *random distributions are not uniform*. What you're describing is typically called a pity RNG (where you chances improve the more you fail), and this is not a common or general-purpose RNG need, so it is not part of the stdlib. It shouldn't be difficult to implement if you try, however. Have you made any attempt to implement this, or research how such a thing is implemented?

Comment: @Adrian all reasonable/general purpose (P)RNGs are uniform, and they normally return uniformly distributed discrete (i.e. integer) variates.  these can be easily transformed into uniform floats, and from there you build more complicated distributions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems trivial to implement given `rand.Float32()` or `rand.Float64()`.  Without seeing your code it's difficult to give much code.

You can just repeatedly sample uniform floats and compare to a varying probability of success.  This probability goes up on misses and down on hits.

For example:

```
func did_crit_hit(prob_success *float64) bool {
    p := *prob_success
    hit := rand.Float64() < p
    if hit {
        p = math.Max(0, p - 0.1)
    } else {
        p = math.Min(1, p + 0.1)
    }
    *prob_success = p
    return hit
}
```

you might want to do something more complicated than just changing by a fixed increment, but hopefully that gives you an idea.